# Make a node Codable in swift

Tags: swift, scenekit, codable, scnnode

I'd like to use a simple `FileManager` to persist an object, which requires `Codable` to work. The issue is that the object I'm trying to persist contains an `SCNNode`, which would require me to somehow mane `SCNNode` codable.

I tried to make it `Codable` by using code like this:

```
class CodebleNode: Codable {

    var name: String?
    var Xposition: Float
    var Yposition: Float
    var Zposition: Float
    
    static func createCodableNode(from node: SCNNode) -> CodableNode {
        let codableNode = CodableNode(name: node.name, xposition: node.position.x, yposition: node.position.y, zPosition: node.position.z)
        return codableNode
    }
    
    init(name: String?, xposition: Float, yposition: Float, zPosition: Float){
        self.name = name
        Xposition = xposition
        Yposition = yposition
        Zposition = zPosition
    }
}
```

But it would be tedious to implement a similar wrapper to support *every* `SCNGeometry`.

Would `CoreData` solve this problem or is there any simple code to do that?

Comment: SCNNode conforms to [NSSecureCoding](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nssecurecoding), you might want to check out if that is of use for you.

Comment: I wanted to be able to save data with a FileManager and I couldn't find any information how to do that. I'll edit my text.

Comment: Because I thought that CoreData might not require Codable, but I read through my the internet, I saw that Core Data requires that, too. And the FileManager does the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SceneKit predates Swift's 4's Codable API, and was never augmented to supported it. Instead, it supports Objective-C's `NSCoding` API (`NSSecureCoding`, to be exact).

It's actually possible to leverage the `SCNNode` implementation of `NSCodable` to wrap it into a Codable archive. Essentially you just use an `NSArchiver` to wrap the object into a `Data`, and that `Data` can then be encoded with `Codable`. It's possible to neatly tuck this all away into a property wrapper, which I demonstrate here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/71279637/3141234